# exec command won't interpret windows path string

Tags: python, windows, path

I want to execute a python program using the exec
command, but whether i use a forward slash or a backward
slash, i get an error:

```
>>> exec(r"M:/oskar.py")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    M:/oskar.py
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>> exec(r"M:\oskar.py")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    M:\oskar.py
       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

what am i doing wrong?

using python 3.10.4 on windows 10

thx for your help.

Comment: `exec()` is for executing Python code that is stored in a string, not executing a file at a given path.

Comment: Ah, yes. Back in Python2 i was using "execfile" not "exec". duh. New to me that "execfile" was removed in Python3. Command to use is actually `exec(open(filename).read())`  Thanks, folks.